# Intermittent NPE in OptaPlanner constraint streams

Tags: optaplanner

I've been struggling to reproduce this exception, which is unfortunately an intermittent failure in an OptaPlanner project I'm leading.  Any insights would be much appreciated:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The move thread with moveThreadIndex (2) has thrown an exception. Relayed here in the parent thread.
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.thread.OrderByMoveIndexBlockingQueue.take(OrderByMoveIndexBlockingQueue.java:147)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.forageResult(MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.java:195)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.decideNextStep(MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.java:160)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:88)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:99)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:209)
    at com.greyorange.taskscheduler.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:99)
    at com.greyorange.taskscheduler.Optimizer.solve(Optimizer.java:54)
    at com.greyorange.taskscheduler.behavior.TwoBotsTests.testTwoBotsTwoTasks(TwoBotsTests.java:197)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
Caused by: org.kie.api.runtime.rule.ConsequenceException: Exception executing consequence for rule "Minimize makespan" in com.greyorange.taskscheduler.costs: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.optaplanner.constraint.streams.common.inliner.WeightedScoreImpacter.impactScore(int, org.optaplanner.constraint.streams.common.inliner.JustificationsSupplier)" because "scoreImpacter" is null
    at org.drools.core.runtime.rule.impl.DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.java:39)
    at org.drools.kiesession.agenda.DefaultAgenda.handleException(DefaultAgenda.java:935)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.innerFireActivation(RuleExecutor.java:460)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkAndFire(RuleExecutor.java:101)
    at org.drools.core.concurrent.AbstractRuleEvaluator.internalEvaluateAndFire(AbstractRuleEvaluator.java:33)
    at org.drools.core.concurrent.SequentialRuleEvaluator.evaluateAndFire(SequentialRuleEvaluator.java:43)
    at org.drools.kiesession.agenda.DefaultAgenda.fireLoop(DefaultAgenda.java:748)
    at org.drools.kiesession.agenda.DefaultAgenda.internalFireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:695)
    at org.drools.kiesession.agenda.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:687)
    at org.drools.kiesession.session.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.internalFireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1092)
    at org.drools.kiesession.session.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1083)
    at org.drools.kiesession.session.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1075)
    at org.optaplanner.constraint.streams.drools.DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirector.calculateScore(DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirector.java:85)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.doAndProcessMove(AbstractScoreDirector.java:222)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.thread.MoveThreadRunner.run(MoveThreadRunner.java:147)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.optaplanner.constraint.streams.common.inliner.WeightedScoreImpacter.impactScore(int, org.optaplanner.constraint.streams.common.inliner.JustificationsSupplier)" because "scoreImpacter" is null
    at org.optaplanner.constraint.streams.drools.common.AbstractRuleContext.runConsequence(AbstractRuleContext.java:51)
    at org.optaplanner.constraint.streams.drools.common.UniRuleContext.lambda$newRuleBuilder$c987a6e2$1(UniRuleContext.java:43)
    at org.drools.model.functions.Block3$Impl.execute(Block3.java:40)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.consequence.LambdaConsequence.evaluate(LambdaConsequence.java:76)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.innerFireActivation(RuleExecutor.java:454)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

The constraint "minimize makespan" which is referenced in the stack trace is as follows:

```
  protected Constraint minimizeMakespan(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(CandidateAssignment.class)
        .filter(CandidateAssignment::isAssigned)
        .filter(assignment -> !assignment.isCommitted())
        .penalizeConfigurable("Minimize makespan",
            (candidateAssignment) -> candidateAssignment.getLastTimeSampleIndex() * ApplicationProperties.PERIOD_SECONDS());
  }
```

The first filter removes any unassigned planning entity (checking that both the planning variables of the entity are non-null, as both planning variables are nullable).  There should be no chance of NPE in that method.

Comment: Although this does certainly look like a bug in OptaPlanner, without a runnable piece of code that would reasonably reliably reproduce it, I do not think we will be able to do anything about it.

Comment: Would love to hand off a copy of the code to you guys, but unfortunately it's unlikely to be allowed off our network.  I'll see what I can do, though.  Thanks for the quick reply.

EDIT: I should also mention, this NPE has been thrown while evaluating other constraints.  Doesn't seem to be a pattern.  And I'm running a moveThreadCount of AUTO.

Comment: Yes, this clearly has to do with concurrency, and not any particular constraint.

Comment: One thing I just noticed: you use configurable constraint weights. Is there any chance that the constraints where this throws are disabled? (Weight == 0.) These should never be executed, and that would be the bug, but it would also explain this exception.

Comment: In my case, i'm working with an objective function that maps to R^4 (i'm using a single "hard" tier and 3 "soft").  None of my weights are the zero vector, but all of them are 1 in one coordinate and 0 elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for reporting this issue. We're tracking the issue here: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2707
We need a reproducer to fix it.

Comment: Are you using Quarkus? Which version of OptaPlanner are you using? Why version of Java are you using? We're looking for common patterns with [the other person reporting this](https://groups.google.com/g/optaplanner-dev/c/iuBlw0foB6c)

Comment: Great and thanks for the responses here from you and the OptaPlanner team.  Some info that might be helpful: no Quarkus (yet..), Java 17 (Open JDK), and OptaPlanner 8.20.Final.

The problem is a variation on job-shop scheduling.  Two planning variables: (1) robot, (2) timegrain (using time grain design pattern.  Over-constrained so both are nullable.)

I've seen this issue most reliably via the construction heuristic phase (allocate entity from queue, default config).

Comment: Wish I could do more to track it down, but we have a lot of other tickets to work through on this project and we have a usable workaround (in the cases it hits this exception, we use a custom greedy solution).  Since we're operating against a receding time horizon and repeatedly planning, this is workable for now.

Answer (score 0):

> The move thread with moveThreadIndex (2) has thrown an exception. Relayed here in the parent thread.

Ignore this wrapping. It just means the exception did occur in a child thread (a move thread) and is relayed on the solver thread for your convenience.

It neither proves or disproves it's a concurrency bug.

> NullPointerException: Cannot invoke ...WeightedScoreImpacter.impactScore(...)" because "scoreImpacter" is null

Ok, that's is weird, because the scoreImpacter is never null.

A) So it could be a concurrency bug (for example if the scoreImpacter field is set after construction and then run another thread without a CPU cache refresh (see Java Concurrency in practice)). But that's very, very unlikely. It would mean KieBase doesn't do a form of synchronized/volatile before starting to create KieSessions.

B) What Lukas suggested: a zero weight constraint, that somehow got build anyway and no fail fasts happened. But than it would reproduce every time and should reproduce with moveThreadCount=0 too.

Either way, only a reproducer can help at this point. It should be reproducible on every run if you're using environmentMode=REPRODUCIBLE and not using Simulated Annealing (or do use SA but switch to stepCount termination).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this was a bug in Drools that was [recently fixed](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/commit/ba932641d4298a403ccef1b1995576c822fd639b).
Please retry with OptaPlanner 8.23.0.Final, when we release it in the coming weeks.

(That said, without a code reproducer, I can not be sure. I only know an issue was fixed with similar symptoms.)